# Why WinExe doesnt works when windows starts before user login?

Tags: winexe

I'm running tools called winexe on linux to run service on windows from linux. Each time, my apache services is down, that tools will monitor and automatically restart it. It works fine every time, except when Windows just rebooted, winexe cannot access Windows. 
I need to login to windows first and **do nothing**, and winexe can works again.

My question is what's make winexe cannot works, if I'm not login after reboot? Because even if I'm login, I do nothing but winexe can work after that. Is there any services triggered when I'm login after reboot or is there any requirement services before winexe can access windows?

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

Try run winexe as follows:
`winexe -debug-stderr --system -U "domain/admin%pass" //host "cmd /c <command>`